# How to detect the missing resouce from a web site hosted in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am deploying a web site written by someone else. It requires quite a lot of resouces which I am not sure I have them all. Now the site is encountering "***Object reference not set to an instance of an object***" error, which I belive is caused by some missing resouces.

There may be 2 kinds of situations.

- some files are missing.
- files are there but missing some content in it.

I am wondering if there's a way to detect what resource are being looked for when the error happend. Could IIS logging or tracing be helpful? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from the thrown exception.

Comment: Thanks. I already got the stacktrace, but that only tells me where the exception is thrown. Since I don't have the source code, I still don't know what resource is missing.

Comment: This is a difficult one because there is so little information to work with. What you could try is to load the specific assembly where the exception is thrown from, into a .net decompiler (dotPeek, reflector) and try to find the line where the exception is thrown. Maybe this would tell you what is missing or puts you in the right direction.

Comment: That's a bit helpful. Thanks.